# I can't open Jupyter on OSX from terminal because of tornado.log

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tornado

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling upgraded versions of pip, and notebook. Still the same error.

When I type `jupyter notebook`, this appears:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Code/first-python-notebook/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Code/first-python-notebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Code/first-python-notebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 572, in <module>
    from .extensions import (
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Code/first-python-notebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/extensions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tornado.log import LogFormatter
ImportError: No module named tornado.log
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265338/jupyter-notebook-importerror-no-module-named-tornado-log)?

Comment: I might suggest you use PyCharm instead. It also supports Notebooks

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I tried installing Tornado again using this command. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @cricket_007
I am trying PyCharm. It cant connect to Jupyter notebook, citing the same error.

Comment: You're in a virtualenv? Did you activate it before  using the command in that link?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I did. I did not create a new virtualenv but configured PyCharm to work in the same virtualenv I am using.

Comment: I'd suggest just creating a new one. Besides, if just starting to learn python, you'd go for python3

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for an alternate way of doing this, which I personally found much easier. Using Anacondas.
Get anaconda here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads
And the further installation instructions here: http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id3

Comment: Will this run in the same virtualenv I activated?

Comment: Anaconda is rather large install only to run Jupyter